# Python 2d Ratio Plot with weighted mean trendline

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

Hello and thanks in advance. I am starting with a pandas dataframe and I would like like make a 2d plot with a trendline showing the weighteed mean y value with error bars for the uncertainty on the mean. The mean should be weighted by the total number of events in each bin. I start by grouping the df into a "photon" group and a "total" group where "photon" is a subset of the total. In each bin, I am plotting the ratio of photon events to total. On the x axis and y axis I have two unrelated variables "cluster energy" and "perimeter energy". 
My attempt:

```
#make the 2d binning and total hist
energybins=[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22]
ybins = [0,.125,.25,.5,.625,.75,1.,1.5,2.5]
total_hist,x,y,i = plt.hist2d(train['total_energy'].values,train['max_perimeter'].values,[energybins,ybins])
total_hist = np.array(total_hist)
#make the photon 2d hist with same bins
groups = train.groupby(['isPhoton'])
prompt_hist,x,y,i = plt.hist2d(groups.get_group(1)['total_energy'].values,groups.get_group(1)['max_perimeter'].values,bins=[energybins,ybins])
prompt_hist = np.array(prompt_hist)
ratio = np.divide(prompt_hist,total_hist,out=np.zeros_like(prompt_hist),where = total_hist!=0)
#plot the ratio
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ratio=np.transpose(ratio)
p = ax.pcolormesh(ratio,)
for i in range(len(ratio)):
    for j in range(len(ratio[i])):
        text = ax.text(j+1, i+1, round(ratio[i, j], 2),ha="right", va="top", color="w")
ax.set_xticklabels(energybins)
ax.set_yticklabels(ybins)
plt.xlabel("Cluster Energy")
plt.ylabel("5x5 Perimeter Energy")
plt.title("Prompt Photon Fraction")

def myBinnedStat(x,v,bins):
    means,_,_ = stats.binned_statistic(x,v,'mean',bins)
    std,_ ,_= stats.binned_statistic(x,v,'std',bins)
    count,_,_ = stats.binned_statistic(x,v,'count',bins)
    return [ufloat(m,s/(c**(1./2))) for m,s,c in zip(means,std,count)]
```

I can then plot an errorbar plot, but I have not been able to plot the errorbar on the same axis as the pcolormesh. I was able to do this with hist2d. I am not sure why that is. I feel like there is a cleaner way to do the whole thing.

This yields a plot [image: like]

Comment: Does explicitly defining the axes to be plotted on work: `ax.errorbar(...)`?

Comment: I tried adding a line in the plotting where I plot using ```ax.errorbar()``` It plots the two plots in the same figure, but next two each other. Interestingly if I have the underlying plot a hist2d rather than a pcolormesh it will work. Maybe that means pcolormesh does not support this? @busybear

Comment: Perhaps your x values aren't matching up between the two plots? If you provide your output it might give some insight.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @busybear I am using the "energybins" vector for the x values of the hist2ds that are making the ratio and for the errorbar plot. I added a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pcolormesh` plots each element as a unit on the x axis. That is, if you plot 8 columns, this data will span 0-8 on the x axis. However, you also redefined the x axis ticklabel so that 0-10 is labeled as 11-21.

For your errorbars, you specified x values at 11-21, or so it looks, which is where the data is plotted. But is not labeled since you changed the ticklabels to correspond to pcolormesh.

This discrepancy is why your two plots do not align. Instead, you could use "default" x values for `errorbar` or define x values for `pcolormesh`. For example, use:

```
ax.errorbar(range(11), means[0:11], yerr=uncertainties[0:11])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help